# Android, Mediaplayer mp3, disturbing sounds

Tags: java, android, audio, mp3, media-player

I am playing a mp3 file from a local source with `MediaPlayer`.
The song is played, but there are also weird "scratch" sounds that can be heard.
This is happening with every song.
Also after a short while (depends on song) the player stops playing, this takes from 5 seconds up to 2 minutes.

`Error: /MediaPlayer(957): Error (1,-2147483648)`

I searched a lot in google.. no solution.
Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Where is your song? Raw file or Streaming?

Comment: Code is simple: Mediaplayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
  mp.setDataSource(Folder + "tmp.mp3");
  mp.prepare();
  mp.sstart();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the song doesn't glitch in any other media player, then consider re-encoding using mpg123 for instance. It may come from an encoding problem more than your android programming.

Comment: that's quite complicated. Can't you change your mp3 source ?